evaluation and coevaluation, FDVS case
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbf F$. We may obtain the evaluation map $\text{ev}:V\otimes V^*\to\mathbf F$ via universal property of the tensor product; the coevaluation map can then be defined as the dual of the evaluation map.
Is it possible to show the zig-zag identities
$$(\text{id}_V\otimes\text{ev})(\text{coev}\otimes\text{id}_V) = \text{id}_V$$
and
$$(\text{ev}\otimes\text{id}_{V^*})(\text{id}_{V^*}\otimes\text{coev}) = \text{id}_{V^*}$$
without picking a basis?

Here's a more fundamental question: can you even show that the double dual map $V \to (V^{\ast})^{\ast}$ is an isomorphism without picking a basis? If not the coevaluation map doesn't have the right target for these compositions to even be defined. And even more fundamental than that: can you even define "finite-dimensional" without picking a basis?

well, I was going to define trace via the isomorphism from $V\otimes V^\to\text{End}(V)$, which is a more general case of the isomorphism from $W\otimes V^\to\text{Hom}(V, W)$, then take the definition of dimension to be the trace of the identity map.

But you already need $V$ to be finite-dimensional to get these isomorphisms, so this is circular as a definition of finite-dimensionality.

what about taking the definition of finite dimensional to be "has a spanning set," so that we have finiteness without actually knowing what the dimension is? then the trace definition could reveal the actual dimension, whereas the previous definition would suffice to prove that the double dual map is an isomorphism.

Presumably you mean "finite spanning set." Yes, that works as a definition, but I still think you'll have trouble proving anything else from here without choosing a basis (basically because it's not true that finitely generated modules are projective; and to prove that vector spaces are projective you have to choose a basis). Also, the trace still does not tell you the dimension in positive characteristic!
